# Tracking multiple domains while obtaining single reports also

Tags: google-analytics

I own 4 websites

```
site1.com
shop.site.com
site2.com
site3.com
```

Using [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) information I will get a global report that shows how websites interacts.

How to keep getting separate reports for every website also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to do. You need to create a profile for each domain, then make a filter for each profile to only collect data for a single domain.

For example for `site1.com`:

1. New profile named `site1.com`
2. In the new profile create a filter `Include site1.com traffic only`
3. Filter type set as *Custom filter* and *Include*
4. Filter field as *Hostname*
5. Filter pattern as `^site1\.com$`

Repeat for each domain. Data will only be collected once the profile is created.

([Google's explanation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts#profiles))