# Google Analytics set-up for multiple domain in same site

Tags: google-analytics

We have a single site with all the content for multiple domains in this site. Is there a proper way to separate out analytics for domain.com and domain.com.au?

In the past we had two analytics code set up for each domain. However it does not work as expected because both analytics recording same number of traffic for both domain. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48468/tracking-multiple-domains-while-obtaining-single-reports-also/48472)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the next instructions from GA help:

Set up cross-domain tracking for multiple domains:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en-GB

Tracking Multiple Domains:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876?hl=en-GB